# Postgres where json column "in" casting json to uuid

Tags: postgresql, casting

Given the following data structure I am trying to count the number of answers  to question type messages

- questions are identified by either a non null `node` or `options` column
- answers are identified by non null `previous`

Ideally I'm hoping to return

```
| message             | answer        | count |
|---------------------|---------------|-------|
| Stuffed crust?      | Crunchy crust | 2     |
| Stuffed crust?      | More cheese!  | 1     |
| Pineapple on pizza? | No            | 3     |
| Pineapple on pizza? | Yes           | 2     |
```

I assume once I work out how to get around the casting error above I can work out the counting and grouping, but I can't seem to get that far yet.

> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = uuid
> LINE 24: where previous->'id'::text in (
> ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
WITH data (
    id,
    message,
    node,
    options,
    previous
) AS (
    VALUES
      ('5f0a50c7-2736-45a2-81c0-fad1ca62cbdc'::uuid, 'No', null, null, '{"id": "20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a", "node": "pineapple"}'::json),
      ('ec7cd365-e206-4f21-be37-495914458313'::uuid, 'Yes', null, null, '{"id": "20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a", "node": "pineapple"}'::json),
      ('56240ea2-6bc7-435e-b76f-c874084a234c'::uuid, 'No', null, null, '{"id": "20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a", "node": "pineapple"}'::json),
      ('670d6d09-89d6-4063-ace7-e606f18c2cc2'::uuid, 'Yes', null, null, '{"id": "20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a", "node": "pineapple"}'::json),
      ('25acbc4c-dd27-412c-86b2-8882c80b9c73'::uuid, 'No', null, null, '{"id": "20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a", "node": "pineapple"}'::json),
      
      ('e7ff8b2b-cc4d-4006-a3c4-9efdc8e458db'::uuid, 'More cheese!', null, null, '{"id": "b18059f0-6d38-4898-bbb7-ebdd7e175b82", "node": "stuffed_crust"}'::json),
      ('c3aee52f-e30e-4c83-8c90-9ff890dd0e72'::uuid, 'Crunchy crust', null, null, '{"id": "b18059f0-6d38-4898-bbb7-ebdd7e175b82", "node": "stuffed_crust"}'::json),
      ('965f9936-284f-4e57-838d-bcf90f119a9c'::uuid, 'Crunchy crust', null, null, '{"id": "b18059f0-6d38-4898-bbb7-ebdd7e175b82", "node": "stuffed_crust"}'::json),
      
      -- questions
      ('b18059f0-6d38-4898-bbb7-ebdd7e175b82'::uuid, 'Stuffed crust?', 'stuffed_crust', '["Crunchy crust","More cheese!"]'::json, null::json),
      ('20c98b37-6cf3-47d1-b93a-606b99bb341a'::uuid, 'Pineapple on pizza?', 'pineapple', '["Yes","No"]'::json, null::json)
)
SELECT * from data 
where previous->'id'::uuid in (
    SELECT id::uuid FROM data WHERE options is not null 
);
```

Update

Having had my casting question answered, the query I used to achieve the results i wanted is as follows

```
select d2.message as question, data.message, count(data.message)
from data
join data as d2 on (data.previous->>'id')::uuid = d2.id
where (data.previous->>'id')::uuid in (
    SELECT id FROM data WHERE options is not null   
)
group by question, data.message;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::` operator has a higher precedence than the `->` operator, so you need to use parentheses there. You also need to get the ID as text, not as JSONB as there is no direct cast from jsonb to uuid:

```
where (previous->>'id')::uuid IN (...)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation. Makes sense. I've put the query I've used to get the results I wanted in my answer.

Comment: @BenSwinburne: note that the cast for `id` is not needed as those values are already `uuid` values

Comment: Cheers. I've removed them now.